# Create parent and child relationship using lodash

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Combine both parent and chid JSON arrays based on the index value and add another found attribute to it.

Data:        Comparison field: 
parentJSON - index
childJSON - parent_index

Output:
- parent
- and its children
- parent
- and its children

```
parentJSON:
[{ index:1, name: 'a'}, {index:2, name: 'b'}, {index:3, name: 'c'}, {index:4, name: 'd'}]

childJSON:
[
  { index:1, name: 'aa', parent_index:1}, 
  {index:2, name: 'ab', parent_index:1}, 
  {index:3, name: 'ba', parent_index: 2}, 
  {index:4, name: 'bb', parent_index: 2}, 
  {index:5, name: 'ca', parent_index: 3}, 
  {index:6, name: 'ad', parent_index: 1}
]

output:
[
  { index:1, name: 'a'},
  { index:1, name: 'aa', parent_index:1, found: true}, 
  { index:2, name: 'ab', parent_index:1, found: true},
  { index:6, name: 'ad', parent_index:1, found: true},
  { index:2, name: 'b'},
  { index:3, name: 'ba', parent_index:2, found: true}, 
  { index:4, name: 'bb', parent_index:2, found: true},
  { index:3, name: 'c'},
  { index:5, name: 'ca', parent_index:3, found: true},
  { index:4, name: 'd'},
]
```

[Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/j3iMdfKqi4x4b8xA6vpw?p=preview)

Comment: and why do you get 6 before rest of lessr value?

Comment: @seethrough both json's have index and comparison is done based on parent index and output is the order loaded based on parent index

Comment: Can you include an element that shows `found: false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let parentJSON =
[{ index:1, name: 'a'}, {index:2, name: 'b'}, {index:3, name: 'c'}, {index:4, name: 'd'}]

let childJSON =
[
  { index:1, name: 'aa', parent_index:1}, 
  {index:2, name: 'ab', parent_index:1}, 
  {index:3, name: 'ba', parent_index: 2}, 
  {index:4, name: 'bb', parent_index: 2}, 
  {index:5, name: 'ca', parent_index: 3}, 
  {index:6, name: 'ad', parent_index: 1}
]

let answer = [];

parentJSON.forEach(parent => {
  answer.push(parent);
  
  childJSON.forEach(child => {
   if(child.parent_index === parent.index){
     child.found = true;
      
      answer.push(child);
    }
  })
});

console.log(answer)
```

Without knowing how you are expecting to have `childJSON` that is not exist in `parentJSON`, the above solution made an assumption that all elements of `childJSON` has a `parent_index` link to `parentJSON`.

Do let me know if you updated your question unless this is exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using [lodash](https://lodash.com/), will keep my solution to be all in lodash.

The steps towards this problem will be:

1. Is to map the `childJSON`, to check if the index of their parent exist or not
2. Merge the both array of jsons into one.
3. Sort them by `name` in ascending order.

Writing this in code will be :

```js
var childJSON = [
  { index:1, name: 'aa', parent_index:1}, 
  {index:2, name: 'ab', parent_index:1}, 
  {index:3, name: 'ba', parent_index: 2}, 
  {index:4, name: 'bb', parent_index: 2}, 
  {index:5, name: 'ca', parent_index: 3}, 
  {index:6, name: 'ad', parent_index: 1}
];

var parentJSON = [
   { index:1, name: 'a'},
   {index:2, name: 'b'}, 
   {index:3, name: 'c'}, 
   {index:4, name: 'd'}
   ];


childJSON = _.map(childJSON, function(child) {
    child.found = !!_.find(parentJSON, {index: child.parent_index});
    return child;
});

var newArray = _.concat(childJSON, parentJSON);
newArray = _.sortBy(newArray, ['name']);

console.log(newArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Map the child array to an object or Map using `parent_index` as keys

Then iterate parent array and check the above map for any children to include

```js
var childMap = childJSON.reduce((a,c)=> a.set(c.parent_index, (a.get(c.parent_index)|| []).concat(c)),new Map)

var res = parentJSON.reduce((a,c)=>{
  a.push(c)
  if(childMap.has(c.index)){
    return a.concat(...childMap.get(c.index))
  }
  return a;
},[])

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;}
```

```html
<script>
var parentJSON = [{
  "index": 0,
  "parent_name": "Cline Walters"
}, {
  "index": 1,
  "parent_name": "Tommie Hoover"
}, {
  "index": 2,
  "parent_name": "Rosalie Foreman"
}, {
  "index": 3,
  "parent_name": "Sutton Garza"
}, {
  "index": 4,
  "parent_name": "Vega Estrada"
}, {
  "index": 5,
  "parent_name": "Ballard Long"
}, {
  "index": 6,
  "parent_name": "Ernestine Dalton"
}];

var childJSON = [{
  "index": 0,
  "child_name": "Keisha Simmons",
  "parent_index": 0
}, {
  "index": 1,
  "child_name": "Lane Walsh",
  "parent_index": 0
}, {
  "index": 2,
  "child_name": "Jocelyn Chapman",
  "parent_index": 1
}, {
  "index": 3,
  "child_name": "Weaver Welch",
  "parent_index": 1
}, {
  "index": 4,
  "child_name": "Short Jarvis",
  "parent_index": 2
}, {
  "index": 5,
  "child_name": "Dotson Washington",
  "parent_index": 3
}, {
  "index": 6,
  "child_name": "Pate Bradley",
  "parent_index": 4
}];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them into one array, then sort by parent_index or index

```js
let par = [{ index:1, name: 'a'}, {index:2, name: 'b'}, {index:3, name: 'c'}, {index:4, name: 'd'}]
let child = [{ index:1, name: 'aa', parent_index:1}, {index:2, name: 'ab', parent_index:1}, {index:3, name: 'ba', parent_index: 2}, {index:4, name: 'bb', parent_index: 2}, {index:5, name: 'ca', parent_index: 3}, {index:6, name: 'ad', parent_index: 1}]

let res = [...par, ...child].sort((a, b) => (a.parent_index || a.index) - (b.parent_index || b.index) );
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Not able to figure out why the same logic not working for this json set - https://plnkr.co/edit/9BYcDgsq5zUf8nEX3Feh?p=info

Comment: I’m on mobile, I can’t see the code on plunker @Santa_612